# How to interpolate those signal data with a polynomial?

Tags: r, interpolation, trigonometry, polynomials

I am trying to find the coefficients of a polynomial in R, but I am not sure of which order the polynomial is.

I have data:

```
x=seq(6, 174, by=8)    
y=rep(c(-1,1),11)
```

Now I want to find the (obviously) non-linear function that hits up all these points. Function values should still is in the interval `[-1,1]`, and all these points should be understood as the vertex of a parabola.

[image]

**EDIT**

Actually this is not example data, I just need exactly this function for exactly these points.

I tried to describe it with polynomials up to degree 25 and then gave up, with polynomials it seems that it is only possible to approximate the curve but not to get it directly.

Comments suggested using a sine curve. Does someone know how to get the exact trigonometric function?

Comment: agree with @ZheyuanLi - finding the sinusoid that goes through these points will be just elementary trigonometry.  Finding a polynomial that goes through these points, *and* is confined to [-1,1], will be very difficult -- maybe impossible.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi. I think that is what OP is looking for. Otherwise he might want a spline approximation, e.g., `spline(y~x)`.

Comment: voting to close until we get a little more detail/context.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, maybe the question was unclear. @Zheyuan Li as texted above, I am just interested in the example data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data have a strong characteristic that they are sampled from a sinusoid signal. With restriction that `y` is constrained onto `[-1,1]`, we know for sure the amplitude is 1, so let's assume we want a `sin` function:

```
y = sin((2 * pi / T) * x + phi)
```

where `T` is period and `phi` is phase. The period of your data is evident: `2 * 8 = 16`. To get `phi`, just use the fact that when `x = 6`, `y = -1`. That is

```
sin(12 * pi / T + phi) = -1
```

which gives one solution: `phi = -pi/2 - 12 * pi / T`.

Here we go:

```
T <- 16
phi <- -pi/2 - 12 * pi / T
f <- function(x) sin(x * pi / 8 + phi)

plot(x, y)
x0 <- seq(6, 174, by = 0.2)
y0 <- f(x0)
lines(x0, y0, col = 2)
```

[image]

---

Your original intention to have a polynomial is not impossible, but it can't be an ordinary polynomial. An ordinary polynomial is unbounded. It will tends to `Inf` or `-Inf` when `x` tends to `Inf` or `-Inf`.

Local polynomial is possible. Since you say: *all these points should be understood as the vertex of a parabola*, you seem to expect a smooth function. Then a cubic spline is ideal. Specifically, we don't want a natural cubic spline but a **period cubic spline**. The `spline` function from `stats` package can help us:

```
int <- spline(x[-1], y[-1], method = "periodic", xout = x0)
```

Note, I have dropped the first datum, as with "periodic" method, `spline` wants `y` to have the same value on both ends. Once we drop the first datum, `y` values are 1 on both sides.

```
plot(x, y)
lines(int, col = 2)
```

[image]

I did not compare the spline interpolation with the sinusoid function. They can't be exactly the same, but **in statistical modelling we can use either one to model the underlying cyclic signal / effect**.